# Onnx to mlmodel conversion fails to generate .mlmodel file

Tags: pytorch, coreml, onnx, onnx-coreml

I'm trying to convert Pytorch model to MLModel with Onnx.

My code:

```
import torch
from onnx_coreml import convert
import coremltools

net = BiSeNet(19)
net.cuda()
net.load_state_dict(torch.load('model.pth'))
#net.eval()

dummy = torch.rand(1,3,512,512).cuda()


torch.onnx.export(net, dummy, "Model.onnx", input_names=["image"], output_names=["output"], opset_version=11)

finalModel = convert(model='Model.onnx', minimum_ios_deployment_target='12')
finalModel.save('ModelML.mlmodel')
```

After the code runs Model.onnx is generated, however, .mlmodel file is not generated. There're no errors in the console. This is the output:

```
2020-04-15 21:49:32.367179: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
WARNING:root:TensorFlow version 2.2.0-rc2 detected. Last version known to be fully compatible is 1.14.0 .
WARNING:root:Keras version 2.3.1 detected. Last version known to be fully compatible of Keras is 2.2.4 .
1.4.0
/content/drive/My Drive/Collab/fp/model.py:116: TracerWarning: Converting a tensor to a Python integer might cause the trace to be incorrect. We can't record the data flow of Python values, so this value will be treated as a constant in the future. This means that the trace might not generalize to other inputs!
  size_array = [int(s) for s in feat32.size()[2:]]
/content/drive/My Drive/Collab/fp/model.py:80: TracerWarning: Converting a tensor to a Python integer might cause the trace to be incorrect. We can't record the data flow of Python values, so this value will be treated as a constant in the future. This means that the trace might not generalize to other inputs!
  size_array = [int(s) for s in feat.size()[2:]]
/content/drive/My Drive/Collab/fp/model.py:211: TracerWarning: Converting a tensor to a Python integer might cause the trace to be incorrect. We can't record the data flow of Python values, so this value will be treated as a constant in the future. This means that the trace might not generalize to other inputs!
  size_array = [int(s) for s in feat.size()[2:]]
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: I assume there is _some_ output in the console? What does it say?

Comment: I've edited the question with console output.

Comment: This is not enough information for me to go on, unfortunately. Is the ONNX model at least correct? i.e. if you run model with the ONNX runtime, does it give the same output as the original PyTorch model.